# Showing interactive "popup" when button pressed

Tags: android

There is a Maps activity that shows user's location and allows to click a button, which when pressed kind of shows a popup with another button and some text. The background is then darkened and froze so we can not interact with it as long as we do not click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.

I've tried to add another `ConstraintLayout` parent in my XML and just activate and inactivate it but the background is still accessible.

Any ideas?

**Before clicking:**

[image: before clicking]

**After clicking:**

[image: after clicking]

Comment: can you show your layout file.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are not supposed to add for what are you using the code (in your case: internship), just add the problem and you are done. This will save us time.

Comment: Sorry about that, just editted. I would show my layout file but i just deleted the "child" constraint layout. I can make it again if needed

Comment: And what've you achieved so far? express that in code.

Comment: Concerning this particular problem, we can say that i havn't achieved anything. I just need an idea/concept that i might don't know about and then i'll be able to learn how to do it

Comment: Why not use a dialog? I suggest you look into dialogFragments (there are android tutorials on them). The nice thing about dialogFragments is that you can define a layout file for them, just like you do with an activity, and it has the desired effect of 'disabling' background inputs.

Comment: You can add a layout above your map with darkened background and make that layout clickable so layout below it would be inaccessible. Then you can show hide that layout as per your need.

Comment: @DharakBhatt I actually like this idea!

Comment: Yes, that works. I have already tried that.